# Allow only certain people to view a file

Tags: security, lamp

Let's say I have a swf with a movie or something (it's a stream actually but it doesn't really matter).

I created a quite secure way to get to the page where it is displayed (as embed). The only problem is this:

How do I stop someone to view source or use something like Firebug and send the address of the file to somebody else.

I want them to see the result but not be able to send it to anyone else.

The platform for my site is LAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.

- if you don't want the client to know something, the only option is to not tell it;
- if you don't tell the client where the file is, he can't possibly view it.

What you should do instead, is to have some authentication and authorization in place, so that only authenticated and authorized users can access said address. That way users can share the address as they like, but unauthorized users can only get "Access denied" messages.

This does not prevent authorized users from downloading the file and hosting it somewhere else, though. If you don't trust them not to do this, don't authorize them.

Answer (score 1):

> I created a quite secure way to get to the page where it is displayed

intriguing.  Please describe this secure way in detail.

If its *secure* in the sense that it [authenticates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) and [authorises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorisation) the user, then it provides the security you ask about from the sharing of URLs.

Comment: I generate some tokens, then mail them, they enter the token on the site then they are redirected to a page where they can't enter unless there is a variable in a session with the respective token. The token is checked for valability with a formula that include the time when it was emitted and some other properties. Then the token becomes invalid. The only problem I have is this. A guy who SHOULD enter and have privileges enters the page then uses view source to get the url to the stream and dunno... mail it to some1 or whatever -> of course... is my personal opinion that is pretty secured.

Comment: @zozo: just apply that same mechanism to the stream URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a refer[r]er check to prevent users accessing the file directly.

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$components = parse_url($referer);

if ($components['host'] != "www.example.com") {
    // User didn't access file from your site.
}
```

This can be circumvented by spoofing the referer header but should defeat casual users.

Naturally, this doesn't prevent someone downloading and re-hosting the file.

Comment: This would prevent some1 to access the page... but if he/she gets the embed tag and put it in another html file situated anywhere they can still access it... That's my problem.